# DMLOptions - AllowFieldTruncation not working

Tags: apex, batch, dmloptions

I have batch classes performing callout + [insert, update, upsert], so I set up everything about DML first:

```
    this.dml = new SObjectUnitOfWork.DatabaseDML();
    this.unitOfWork = new SObjectUnitOfWork(new List<Schema.SObjectType>{
      Account.getSObjectType(),
      Contact.getSObjectType(),
      Lead.getSObjectType(),
    }, this.dml);
    this.dmlOptions = new Database.DMLOptions();
    this.dmlOptions.AllowFieldTruncation = true;
```

And then:

```
  // Stuff
  record.setDmlOptions(this.dmlOptions);
  // Batch stuff
```

But then I still get:

`Error saving record: STRING_TOO_LONG: [FIELD]: data value too large: 22222 (max length=4)`

Any idea why it fails ?

Comment: Does setting the `dmlOptions` attribute on your batch have anything to do with the DML Operation which eventually gets performed? What happens after you call `setDmlOptions`? Do you call `update record`? Have you tried `Database.update(recordToUpdate, dmlOptions)`?

Comment: @AdrianLarson `record` is registered to a `SObjectUnitOfWork` for an upsert

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

It seems that assigning `DMLOptions` to `SObject` is not working (anymore) (according to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_setOptions ):

```
DMLOptions dmlOptions = new DMLOptions();
dmlOptions.allowFieldTruncation  = true;
SObject object = new Account( Name = 'Stack' );
object.setOptions(dmlOptions);

Database.insert(new SObject[] { object }, false);
```

Assigning `DMLOptions` to Database (for each records then) is working (according to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_insert_4 ):

```
DMLOptions dmlOptions = new DMLOptions();
dmlOptions.allowFieldTruncation  = true;
dmlOptions.optAllOrNone          = true;
SObject object = new Account( Name = 'Stack' );

Database.insert(new SObject[] { object }, dmlOptions);
```